# Filtering Spark Datasets on a single column using a lambda function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, lambda, filtering, apache-spark-dataset

Im trying to speed-up filtering by **avoiding the deserialization of every row** as my dataset contains large number of rows. I want to allow spark to filter based on a single column (e..g `col1`), thus avoiding to deserialize the whole row. Also, i care about returning a `Dataset[MyEntry]`, similar to the input rather than a `Dataset[Row]`.

```
// The three filteres were broadcasted as a Map 
// with the key being the name of the filter and value being 
// the filter itself
// dataSet is Dataset[MyEntry]

case class MyEntry(col1: Int, col2: Int, col3: Int)

val allFilterNames = Array("one","two","three")

dataSet.filter(value => {
          def foo(value: MyEntry): Boolean = {
            var found = false
            for (entry <- allFilterNames) {
              if (broadcastVariable.value.get(entry).get.contains(value.col1)) {
                return true
              }
            }
            found
          }
          foo(value)
})
```

**Context:** I am trying to filter a Spark Dataset column based on a set of broadcasted set membership structures (e.g. Bloom filter) contained within a map (key: filter name, value: actual filter). I want to check if the value of a column exists in the (e.g. 3) broadcasted filters. If the value exists then the whole row is retained. Otherwise, the row is filtered. I used a lambda function and it works. However, this comes at a cost where the whole row will be deserialized every time i perform the check. I want to avoid that overhead by applying the same function over a single column instead (i.e. allow spark to deserialize a single column instead of the whole row). The code above works well when using the lambda function. The **solution** that im looking for needs to be **cheaper in time** compared to the above solution (i.e., pass on the whole dataset just once)

Comment: I'm not sure whether the `Row.getXXX` functions family can solve your problem. At least you can try it and test the performance

Comment: I was under the impression DS and DF were column based. Catalyst may be smart enough here. In tradtional rdbms u filter via index and then go to page is...